# Freediving schools in Indonesia

Tags: indonesia, water-sports

Where can I find freediving schools in Indonesia?

I've heard there are some around Bali but I'm also interested in freediving in Java, Komodo & Sulawesi. Any insider tips appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I will not be able to cover all areas in Indonesia that I'm interested in, as I haven't been to all of them.

But someone may be able to help with the rest (Java & Sulawesi) in the future?

---

#### Bali

All the freediving schools are in east Bali. In Amed & Tulamben.

In Amed there are [Apneista](http://apneista.com) (the oldest school) & [Fusion Freedive](http://fusionfreedive.com/).

In Tulamben (15 drive north of Amed) there is [Apnea Bali](http://www.apneabali.com/).

---

#### The Gili islands

Gili Trawangan has [Freedive Gili,](http://www.freedivegili.com/) ran by [Michael Board](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Board) – Competitive Freediver (103m CWT) and multiple British record holder.

Gili Air has [Freedive Air](http://goo.gl/maps/yZOpu), it belongs to the same people owning Apnea Bali in Tulamben. Freedive Air opened in July 2015.

Gili Air also has [Blue Marine Dive Resort](http://www.bluemarinedive.com/page/freediving), offering freediving and scuba diving.

---

#### Komodo national park

Labuan Bajo is the city from which every single adventure around Komodo & Rinca islands start.

In Labuan Bajo, there is no dedicated freediving school at the time of writing. But rather some scuba diving schools now branching out to a new business opportunity.

In Labuan Bajo, [Uber Scuba](http://uberscubakomodo.com) and [Manta Rhei](http://www.mantarhei.com) provide these freediving services. I think both are good scuba diving schools (I tried Uber Scuba only though), but I have no idea about the freediving. This is now in August 2015 something they just started doing.

---

#### Final note

Freediving seems to be exploding now (in 2015) in Indonesia. So a lot of info is missing on internet.

Give a couple of phone calls to local scuba diving schools to ask them any info on this if you want some insider information.

As seen above, some scuba diving schools are now also trying to do freediving school. For the better or the worst, it gives you more options to practice or learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do Freediving you also have Aurelie and Yoram ( He is a vice champion of freediving in the deep diver category) based at [Dragon Dive Komodo](https://www.dragondivekomodo.com). They offered also freediving liveaboard experience.